# Operating system's performance

Tags: operating-system, processor

Will there be a difference in the performance of a 32 bit operating system running on 64 bit processor and a 32 bit operating system running on 32 bit processor?

Answer (score 1):

Just realized this didn't specify x86.  I don't know if any ARMv8 CPUs are slower in ARMv7 mode than a similar-cost ARMv7 CPU.

You can't really compare apples-to-apples, because there's no such thing as a 64-bit CPU that's exactly the same as a 32-bit CPU except for supporting 64-bit mode.  There are always other microarchitectural changes, too. (Like from Pentium M to Core2 on Intel.)

---

If we're talking about x86, then **no.  A 64-bit *capable* x86 CPU is no worse at running 32-bit code**.  This is called "legacy mode", as opposed to "compat mode" (32-bit user-space under 64-bit OS), but they perform the same.

In fact, the only CPUs that *can't* run in x86-64 mode these days are old, slow, or both.  e.g. using a 32-bit-only CPU means you're running on Pentium4, Pentium-M, or an old Atom!  Or Athlon-XP.  Or an embedded x86 like Geode.

This is the same reason that 32-bit software is still widely used under Windows (although usually under a 64-bit OS).

---

**The option you didn't mention is the high-performance one: 64-bit OS on a 64-bit CPU**, even if you want to run 32-bit user-space code.

Especially if you have more than 1 or 2GB of RAM, it's likely that your system will run faster with a 64-bit kernel.  32-bit kernels *can* use more RAM, but it's ugly and not as fast as if the kernel can have all physical memory mapped into kernel-space virtual memory.  See [Linus Torvald's comments on PAE](https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/) (Physical-Address Extensions)

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more about how x86 CPUs perform, and how to optimize for them.

Comment: So basically,  someone who has bought a 64bit processor and is running a 32 bit OS on it will get the same performance as compared to someone who's using a 32 bit processor and is running the same 32 bit OS on it.

Comment: Actually my office laptop has got a 64 bit processor but the OS on it is 32 bit.  That's why I was wondering if in this case I'm able to get the full performance of the processor.

Comment: @VishalSharma: Then no, you can't, see the last section of my answer.  Most of my answer is answering **what you actually asked: About different CPUs** running the same software, not about your CPU running different software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you wouldn't make full use of all those 64bits. If you have a 32bits OS than you will only use that and not 64. However, if you were to have 64bits OS than it will make full use of those bits.

Also, please have a look at:

https://www.howtogeek.com/194119/why-are-most-programs-still-32-bit-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows/

and

http://www.osnews.com/story/5768

Comment: but what I want to know is what difference, if any,  will be there if the same 32 bit OS is running on 32 bit processor as compared to when it's running on 64 bit processor

Comment: That wasn't the question.